# Need a docker image with tomcat:9.0.55, jre8, and alpine (or similar-weight linux distro)

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, tomcat9, docker-image

I'm looking for a docker image with tomcat:9.0.55 (or .54), jre8 and alpine

- not finding that on docker hub.  Anyone have a tip on how to create it, or find it if it already exists on the hub?

Alternately, I do see "tomcat:9.0.8-jre8-alpine" - is it possible to just get that and update tomcat?

Comment: I guess you could update tomcat, but that's not the way. I'd suggest you get the source Dockerfile and adjust it to retrieve your required version when built.

Comment: @daniu Can you elaborate on "source Dockerfile" ?

Comment: IMHO saving 15 MiB (compressed size, but shareable among images) with respect to [`9-jre8-openjdk-slim`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tomcat/library/tomcat/9-jre8-openjdk-slim/images/sha256-62f0e48366c39d0613cb59d0e341e0c79063fef3cfb973b0fcc5b8c68b81df5e?context=explore) are not worth the effort of building and maintaining your own image.